# django-import-export - Importing ManyToMany from JSON file

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-import-export

I'm trying to import a JSON file that contains a many-to-many relationship but am hitting some problems. This is my code:

**book.json**

```
{
  "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
  "categories": [
      "Fantasy",
      "Action",
      "Adventure"
  ]
}
```

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    guid = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.display_name

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**resources.py**

```py
from import_export import resources
from import_export.fields import Field
from import_export.widgets import ManyToManyWidget
from .models import Book, Category

class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):
    categories = Field(widget=ManyToManyWidget(Category))

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        import_id_fields = ('title',)
```

**importer.py**

```py
from resources import BookResource
from models import Book

with open("book.json", 'r') as f:
        book = '[' + f.read() + ']'
        result = BookResource().import_data(tablib.Dataset().load(book), raise_errors=True, dry_run=True)
```

This seems to run through without errors, and adds the new `book` to the database. The problem is that it doesn't create a new entry in the `book_categories` table (PostgreSQL). I think I'm definitely missing a step somewhere because I haven't defined how to find the correct `category` database entries, given the list of `display_name` strings. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Well, your imports in importer.py aren't correct, but I guess that is a copy problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the short story is, that this case isn't handled by `django-import-export`: if you look at [`ManyToManyWidget.clean()`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/widgets.py#L414), you see that it expects a string of comma separated integers by default. There's a bit you can do there, but it simply wants you to import the Categories first and then the Books.

What I ended up doing was remove the Field and Widget on BookResource and replace it with the widgets dictionary:

```py
class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        import_id_fields = ("title",)
        fields = ("id", "title", "categories")
        widgets = {"categories": {"field": "display_name"}}
```

If you then import Categories first, then your books will be correctly linked. Well, with one modification to the JSON and I wrapped the importer script up, so it can be run on console:

```py
import django
import os

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "testbed.settings"

BOOK_DATA = """[{
  "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
  "categories": "Fantasy,Action,Adventure"
}]"""


def run():
    from bookstore.resources import BookResource
    import tablib

    importer = BookResource()
    dataset = tablib.Dataset()
    data = dataset.load(BOOK_DATA, format="json")
    result = importer.import_data(data, raise_errors=True, dry_run=False)
    print(result.has_errors())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))))
    django.setup()
    run()
```

It is possible to write a JSON specific M2M widget, but then when importing categories, you will need to figure out each row which already exist and which don't. It's doable, so maybe I've put you on the right track to fix it ;)

Comment: Interesting, this seems to work for this very basic example. I'm not really sure how the widgets dictionary is working though -- do you have a link to some documentation on that? I find it a bit odd that JSON arrays aren't supported by default..? I wonder if another method would be converting the JSON to a CSV before importing.

Comment: I found the docs very slim at best, most notably how things tie together. I had to look in the source to figure out the widget structure. In human language: it sets the field argument of the m2m widget associated with the categories field on the books to "display_name", which results in a queryset lookup `filter(display_name__in=values)`. If I had to solve this, I would make at least a custom widget for JSON m2m so you can leverage the fact that the values are already arrays and not string that needs to be split.

Comment: Splitting the array into strings wasn't going to work for all my cases due to there being lists of objects as well. I ended up creating a custom m2m widget which seems to be working so far. I will post it as an answer in case anyone else stumbles upon this issue. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Melvyn, I was able to solve this by creating a custom widget for JSON arrays. I will post it in case anyone else hits this issue.

```
class ManyToManyJSONWidget(ManyToManyWidget):
    def __init__(self, model, field=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if field is None:
            field = 'pk'
        self.model = model
        self.separator = None
        self.field = field

    def clean(self, value, row=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if not value:
            return self.model.objects.none()
        else:
            objs = []
            for i in value:
                obj = self.model.objects.filter(**{
                    '%s__iexact' % self.field: i
                }).first()
                objs.append(obj)
            return objs

    def render(self, value, obj=None):
        return ""
```